# Configuring Facebook's Page Like Button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'd like to have a facebook like button, and I would like it to act like this:
When a user clicks on the button in the user's news feeds the following is shown:
- the name of my site
- link to my web site
- my web site logo
- short description

I am using ruby on rails 3.
Would you be so kind and help me configure this?
Thanks, D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps on how to achieve this. First step is to use the appropriate OpenGraph Tags on your website. These are just additional tags in your HTML head. You can find examples on the [Open Graph Webspage](http://ogp.me/).

Second step is to embed the like button. You can configure the code on the [Facebook Developer page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). When a user clicks on the button, the OpenGraph tags are automatically parsed and the result is shown in the user's stream.

Comment: j0nes, thx for your reply. I am confused with "URL to like" in the first step, and "URL" field in the second step. Do these two collide?

Comment: No, in fact these should be similar - the page at /foo/bar should have the OpenGraph tag URL tag configured at /foo/bar, and the like button should be configured the same way.

Comment: so I need to use only ONE of them - never BOTH TOGETHER?

Comment: No - you should have both of them in place.

Comment: Looks good so far. Use the Facebook OpenGraph Debugger on your webpage to show which OpenGraph information is recognized by Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: this is what I get: 
Inferred Property: The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tag

also, is it possible something is wrong with  property="fb:admins" property

Comment: do I have to be  logged in NOT as my user, but as facebook page MYPAGE user?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16149/discussion-between-j0nes-and-dantes)

Answer (score 1):

Configure your requirement in below page
You can get the required script for facebook like button, by giving inputs to the widget in the page

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: prem, thanks for yur quick response. The first thing that confuses me is - do i have to do the both steps in order to achieve my goal i.e. Step 1 - Get Like Button Code, Step 2 - Get Open Graph Tags, or can I use one of them. The second - suppose I have to use the both steps - I have this code from the first step that comes somewhere inside the html body tag, and then this  Open graph tags that come in _head. I got the code from FB when I entered infos, but I didn't got the result I wanted.

Comment: Am not sure why do you need Open Graph Tags for like button.For like button, from the 2 snippets given by facebook widget, you can copy first one in starting of body tag and second one on, wherever you need the like button.

Comment: You don't need the OpenGraph Tags. However if you want to customize the display of your page in the Facebook stream, this is the tool to use.

Comment: For displaying like button, you dont need the OpenGraph Tags. They are necessary to customize the details displayed when you add 'facebook sharing' from your application